# Plotting variable transformation in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, analytics

I want to plot a graphic with these variables of mi data set called DSET : `NA. ,PI , PC , SPCI`

I want to plot the relationship `NA.( in Y axis) VS (1/SPCI*(PI+PC)) (in X axis)`

I thought that to codify `(1/SPCI*(PI+PC)` ,  `I(1/(DSET$SPCI) * (DSET$PC + DSET$PI))` and `(1/(I(DSET$SPCI)*I(DSET$PC+DSET$PI))` were the same, but I got two different plots.

Here are my two different plots :

[image]

[image]

So, which one is correct?, or maybe both are incorrect.

EDIT:

The code for both plots are :

```
plot(I(1/(DSET$SPCI) * (DSET$PC + DSET$PI)),DSET$NA.)
plot(1/(I(DSET$SPCI)*I(DSET$PC+DSET$PI)),DSET$NA.)
```

My graphics are visible?

SECOND EDIT:

The answer was so easy, I just had to take a look at the X-Axis to realise the values are totally different and make a manual calculation for one value to choose one plot.

In fact, I wanted to know more about the use of the I() operator.

Comment: Your plots are not visible for me, and there's also no code that would generate plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more information about `I()` function if you type `?I` into R.

`I()` **isolates the contents in the parentheses from other R code.**

---

I am familiar with `I()` argument when doing quadratic `glm` in R.

For example for model like this:

```
f(y) = alpha + beta*x + gamma*x^2
```

I can choose from two equal expression

expression `y ~ poly(x, 2)` or expression `y ~ I(x^2)`

Hard to tell if anyone of your plots is correct. You should **focus on correct use of parentheses.**